# How to solve Dataframe to_numeric Error (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe that contains float numbers. I want to do numeric operations as sum mult. etc. .
Columns types are object. So i have to change this columns into a numeric columns.
I use to_numeric function but it gives me NaN as a result.

How can i solve this problem?

Code :

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', engine='python', delimiter=';')

#change object columns into a numeric columnn
for i in data.columns :
    data[i] = pd.to_numeric(data[i], errors='coerce')
```

**Dataframe**

```
t0 (actual) t0  t0,lower    t0,upper
0   11861,6318726842    0   0   0
1   4761,43316  5709,1728515625 3776,725188260803   7939,908970830105
2   36,22841951973635   0   0   0
3   583,3716479196096   0   0   0
4   25087,16436661841   26040,7890625   21825,20941707611   31905,394350044822
....
```

**Result :**

```
    t0 (actual) t0  t0,lower    t0,upper
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Can you share the csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, but I assume you could add `decimal=","` to `pd.read_csv`.

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> decimal : str, default ‘.’
> Character to recognize as decimal point (e.g. use ‘,’ for European data).

So your code would look like this:

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', engine='python', delimiter=';', decimal=",")

#change object columns into a numeric columnn
for i in data.columns :
    data[i] = pd.to_numeric(data[i], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thank you, adding decimal solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you change `errors` from `coerce` to `raise`, you will see that `pandas` cannot convert these values to numerical datatype. This is because it does not recognize `,` as a decimal separator (by default, it is `.`). Which means having `errors = 'coerce'` will replace these values with `NaN`.

If, as it seems, you're trying to convert these values right after reading it from a `.csv` file, you should instead specify the decimal separator used in your `read_csv` call. Then you will not need to convert the values manually.

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', engine='python', delimiter=';', decimal = ',')
```

If, however, these values come from your script, you would need to replace `,` values with `.` in your string values:

```
for i in data.columns :
    data[i] = pd.to_numeric(data[i].str.replace(',','.'), errors='coerce')
```